# StructureMap 2.6.1 cannot override default registrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

For MVC3, StructureMap 2.6.1

**Base Registrations/usage in App1**

```
For<IMyRepository<MyRequest, MyResponse>>().Use<MyRepository>();
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository<MyRequest,MyResponse>
var foo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyRepository<MyRequest, MyResponse>>();
```

**Returns MyRepository as expected...,App2 override attempt**

NOTE:  App2 registers after App1

```
public class MyOverriddenRepository : MyRepository
For<IMyRepository<MyRequest, MyResponse>>().Use<MyOverriddenRepository>();
var overriddenFoo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyRepository<MyRequest, MyResponse>>();
```

**overriddenFoo is of type MyRepository, not MyOverriddenRepository, why??**
**tried same override in App1 and Foo returns MyOverriddenRepository**

**WhatDoIhave in App 1**

```
IMyRepository`2<MyRequest, MyResponse> (IMyRepository`2<MyRequest, MyResponse>)     
408858...  Configured Instance of MyOverriddenRepository, ...
Scoped as:  Transient
20ebeb...  Configured Instance of MyRepository, ...
976143...  Configured Instance of MyRepository, ...
408858...  Configured Instance of MyOverriddenRepository, ...
```

**WhatDoIhave in App 2**

```
IMyRepository`2<MyRequest, MyResponse> (IMyRepository`2<MyRequest, MyResponse>)     
976143...  Configured Instance of MyRepository, ...
Scoped as:  Transient
976143...  Configured Instance of MyRepository, ...
408858...  Configured Instance of MyOverriddenRepository, ...
```

**What is the way to diagnose further?  Trying to see if a structuremap bug or mine?**